# NPM in GitHub Actions Env not installing packages

Tags: github, npm, npm-install, github-actions

I have a repository for a discord.js bot that uses the development version of discord.js-commando.

That means it clones discordjs/Commando instead of installing the package.

I am facing an issue that for some reason GitHub Actions are not able to do that :(

The project shall be on nodejs v12+ on any machine. I guess the error is in installing the package.

Here's the workflow run log:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/discordjs/Commando.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.113.3' to the list of known hosts.
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-08-23T03_19_01_561Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Here's the package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "alphasians-aina",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Alphasians AINA",
  "keywords": [],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Alphasians/AINA",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Alphasians/AINA/issues"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "contributors": [],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "bin": {},
  "man": [],
  "directories": {
    "src": "src",
    "lib": "dist"
  },
  "repository": "github:Alphasians/AINA",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node .",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "commit": "npx --no-install cz",
    "lint": "npx eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "npx eslint . --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/opus": "^0.5.3",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "discord.js": "^12.5.3",
    "discord.js-commando": "github:discordjs/Commando",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ffmpeg-static": "^4.4.0",
    "require-all": "^3.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.5",
    "simple-youtube-api": "^5.2.1",
    "sqlite": "^4.0.23",
    "ytdl-core": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.4.13",
    "commitizen": "^4.2.4",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {},
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public",
    "registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org/",
    "tag": "latest"
  },
  "config": {
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add necessary information to your question, not links to external sites

Comment: James, I have actually linked to the workflow run, since it's an issue related to gh actions... not sure what do you mean by necessary information, everything is included in a paragraph based approach

Comment: Like I said, the information needed to answer the question, should be **in the question**. Not actually linked anywhere. Links can (and most likely will) break in the future, making such questions useless.

Comment: Fixed! Let me know for anything else I can do to improve the question

Answer (score 0):

I forked your repository and updated [your workflow file](https://github.com/krishdevdb/Alphasians-AINA/blob/main/.github/workflows/nodejs.yml) installing `discord.js-comando` manually on another step before the `npm ci` command, after removing it from the `package.json` file.

```yaml
      - run: npm install discord.js@12 discord.js-commando

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm ci
```

And the workflow ran successfully.

- [updated package.json](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/Alphasians-AINA/blob/develop/package.json)
- [forked workflow file](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/Alphasians-AINA/blob/develop/.github/workflows/nodejs.yml)
- [new workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/Alphasians-AINA/runs/3433095832?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: How am I supposed to find the answer to my issue from the working code? The code that was not working was in develop branch?

Comment: I just updated the workflow file you used in the workflow run that returned the error you stated. I wasn't sure the problem was from the package.json even after reading the comments above, so I tried some things on my forked repository and this is the solution I found to make the workflow run successfully. I can open a PR if you want.

Comment: Actually, you ran the code on the main branch, but the wrong code was in the develop branch, so your code still gives an error :(

Comment: Ok, I will check the `develop` branch (you shoukd uodate the question with this information) 

Comment: I found a workaround removing the `discord.js-comando` from the package.json file on the `develop` branch, installing it manually on the workflow file. I updated my answer. Could you check if it works now?